# Can I credit mileage on Garuda to Singapore or Qantas?

Tags: loyalty-programs, indonesia, singapore-airlines, qantas, garuda

I expect to do a fair amount of travel on Garuda Indonesia (GA) going forward.  GA is a Skyteam member that does not grant direct credit to my preferred airline programs (SQ Krisflyer or Qantas); however, it does have a [long list of partners](https://www.garuda-indonesia.com/garudamiles/en/perolehan-miles/terbang.page), many outside Skyteam (ANA, Etihad, etc).

**Is there a way for me to convert my Garuda flights into SQ or QF miles?** Open to hairy, multi-step conversions through hotel or airline programs: for example, I've previously credited Hawaiian mileage to SQ by laundering them through Virgin Australia.